# How to avoid duplicating code for similar stubs?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stub

I have a test file in which I stub the dependencies (repositories mainly) of my tested class. 
Example of repository stubbed (shortened from about 200 lines):

```
internal class doerRepository : IDoerRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Doer> ActiveDoers
    {
        get
        {
            Account account = new Account();
        //Property setting for account

        Zone zone = new Zone();
        //Property setting for zone

        Doer doer = new Doer();
        doer.Zone = doerZone;
        doer.Account = doerAccount;

        var list = new List<Doer>();
        list.Add(doer);
        return list.AsQueryable();
    }
 }
```

}

And a test method looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void IsValidDoer_DoerIsValid()
{
    var doerValidation = new DoerValidation(new doerRepository());
    //Assert things
}
```

The problem is that this entity environment (it stubs about half of the database) is my baseline. I have about 25 tests to make for this test file. For each test, I have to slightly change the stub (try with an invalid zone, an invalid account, etc.). I end up copy pasting the 200 lines to change one little thing (and I have to rename the class over that).

Is it possible to reuse the stub code and just make the relevant changes? 
I tried this, but the value I change is not updated

```
internal class doerRepository2 : IDoerRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Doer> ActiveDoers
    {
        get
        { List<Doer> list = new doerRepository().ActiveDoers.ToList();
          list.First().Account = new Account();
          return list.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid writing stubs by hand by using some isolation framework. It allows one to dynamically created stubs. I personally prefer [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). With it your test can be written this way.

```
[Test]
public void IsValidDoer_DoerIsValid()
{
  var mockRepository = new Mock<IDoerRepository>();
  var activeDoers = CreateSpecificDoerList();
  mockRepository.Setup(r => r.ActiveDoers).Returns(activeDoers);

  var doerValidation = new DoerValidation(mockRepository.Object);

  // Assert things
}
```

Here you're creating a dynamic stub and telling it that `ActiveDoers` should return your specific list of doers.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to solve this by adding extra setter properties on my stubs to be able to set values I return in the stub methods that return the mock data to support the method under test.

This way I usually get away with just one stub since I can re-purpose it by setting different combinations of data to be returned.

Comment: Yes, this may also add flexibility!